# inheritance in python 2.7.x

Tags: python, inheritance, super

I did this code:

```
class Square(Quad):
    def __init__(self, linesValue):
        """Calls the builder in quad (same)"""
        super(Square, self).__init__(linesValue)
```

then It said I have to send type as first arg, so I did this:

```
class Square(Quad):
    def __init__(self, linesValue):
        """Calls the builder in quad (same)"""
        super(type(Square), self).__init__(linesValue)
```

then it said obj must be instance of subinstance of class, and as you can see **Square(Quad)** it is.

Comment: Not sure it will solve your issue, but the call to `super` should be *in* `__init__` (it's currently at the scope of the function definition).

Comment: How did you define `Quad`? It should inherit from `object`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Considering your indentation is correct then in Python2 a class should inherit from `object`, otherwise it would be considered as a classic class. And you can't use `super` on a classic class.

So, if `Quad` is defined like this, then it is wrong:

```
class Quad:
    def __init__(self, x):
       pass
```

And instantiating `Square` will raise error like this:

```
>>> Square(12)
    ...
    super(Square, self).__init__(linesValue)
TypeError: must be type, not classobj
```

Change `Quad` to inherit from `object`:

```
class Quad(object):
    def __init__(self, x):
       print x
```

**Demo:**

```
>>> Square(12)
12
<__main__.Square object at 0x93e286c>
```

Comment: There are lot of ways to get error, and OP seems to used all of them consecutively

Comment: @latheiere Unless OP provides exact code and traceback all we can do is guess. ;-)

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know that I HAS to be from object

Answer (score 2):

You have bad indentation, and so your super is outside of `__init__`. Compare:

```
>>> class Square(Quad):
...     def __init__(self, linesValue):
...         """Calls the builder in quad (same)"""
...         super(Square, self).__init__(linesValue)
...
>>>
```

and

```
>>> class Square(Quad):
...     def __init__(self, linesValue):
...         """Calls the builder in quad (same)"""
...     super(type(Square), self).__init__(linesValue)
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
TypeError: super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type
```

and

```
>>> class Square(Quad):
...     def __init__(self, linesValue):
...         """Calls the builder in quad (same)"""
...     super(Square, self).__init__(linesValue)
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
   ...
TypeError: super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type
```

Comment: There are lot of ways to get error, and OP seems to used all of them consecutively

Comment: And the super outside the __init__ was a problem in stackoverflow's topic maker, fixed it